# wp_post->post_parent object returning 0

Tags: theme-development, menus, sub-menu

I'm developing a Wordpress theme and I've registered a new menu location (called primary menu) and am using a menu with it.  In my menu, I have a page called "tier-2 page" under a page called "tier-1 page".

I want to get the ID of the parent page ("tier-1 page") while on the child page ("tier-2 page").  I've tried `$post->post_parent`, `get_post()->post_parent`, `get_post_ancestors($post->ID)` and all of them return 0.

At this point, I have no idea why I can't retrieve the ID of the parent page.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

kraftner is probably right but I recommand you to stop using global $post. I mean it's not bad but there are often issues with this big array that can be modified by almost everything running on the wp install.

So to me it's not very safe. I prefer using `get_queried_object()` and it works quite the same way :

```
$parent_ID = get_queried_object()->post_parent;
```

It retrieves data according to the current page. It uses the global `$wp_query` instead. Be careful here we try to get post_parent property so don't run this code on a category page you'd get a warning.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you haven't globalized `$post` before using it:

```
global $post
```

Have a look at the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) if you need more detailed info.